small space between small walls ends up filled with material



I am making an RJ45 connector. To handle the tolerances, I use a clip that pushes the connector when inserted down. Unfortunately, the needed separation is filled with material. The printer is an Ultimaker S3.
Any hints?
Update It might have been the filament (or the setting of the filament in Cura). I am new to 3d printing and bought this printer second hand, it included a number of rolls of filaments. I've ordered true Ultimaker filaments. However, in the mean time, another PLA filament worked significantly better although not perfect.

At least I am happy this is not supposed to be like this :-)

your printer is oozing a lot.

Strange, my experience with Ultimaker printers taught me that they are generally very well calibrated, oozing of the amounts I see in the image is not something I have seen before. Are you sure the temperature is not too high? Looking at the base of your print, it also look like it is overextruding, you might want to check if 100 mm of extrusion is also 100 mm of filament. Please check this and report in your question. What is the retraction? Please share some of your slicer parameters with us, see https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/395/helpful-templates-help-us-help-you.

The slicer parameteres are  pure defaults. I use generic PLA settings. The green and the grey filaments are PLA. Buildplate = 60, printer core is 200 (initial 190, final 185).

Don't rollback edits of other users, this is perfectly normal that questions are edited here. Even if they look trivial, we try to maintain good questions. Starting with a bunch of photos is not how you start a question, nor do we add "update"; just update the question. The slicer parameters should also go into the question. Furthermore, your update is factually an answer, as you do not see the problem anymore. Please put your update in an answer, currently, this is a low quality question.

I have no problem with reasonable edits but I just don't like this pedantic editing done for points only; I always roll them back. They have no information and they sometimes remove intentions. So I prefer people to stay away from my text unless you fix a real error. I am a newbie here but have a long history on other stacks.

Is it possible that the mystery roll has a lower melting point than the setting you had in Cura? It looks like a print with PLA filament, but PETG settings.

No, they both were the same PLA settings. 200 degree. I am waiting for new rolls from Ultimaker to see how that looks like.

Then still you've got an answer in your question, too bad that you aren't willing to post that as an answer. Also, those who edit here do not gain points as they are high rep users, you should know that. I'd vote to close this question but I refrain from any voting on this question.

I've been on stack overflow for 10 years, first time I am getting such bad vibes from @Oscar. You're here to help, not run the show or apply your private standards, this is an open forum and you have to live in a community and people have different standards. You come over as very pedantic and unfriendly, especially to a new contributor.

I agree with @Trish 's assessment that you're having ooze of melted filament from the nozzle during the travel movement at the "7 o'clock" position of the object in your picture.
Is there the chance that you've changed your print core to a larger aperture nozzle than the settings you have in Cura, e.g. you have an 0.8mm nozzle core installed and your settings in Cura are for 0.4? Confirm the printer nozzle settings in your slicer match the nozzle actually installed.

No, the printer core is AA 0.4mm. This properly set in Cura. Have now tried with other filament. It is a now free, but still seems to ooze more than I would have expected.

btw, I do not see a comment from @Trish?

@PeterKriens https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/23418/small-space-between-small-walls-ends-up-filled-with-material#comment42225_23418

As comments are not always kept for the life of the answer, they may be deleted, it is generally not a good idea to base your answer on the reference of a comment, preferably you build your answer on this observation rather than linking to the comment.
